# Getting a weird error with my for loops in C

Tags: c, for-loop

I am making a program in C that counts the number of letters in each word of an input and then print them out as a histogram. I am using a lot of for loops in this program, and I am getting the following error with them:

```
letter_size_chart.c:35:37: error: expected expression
    for (i = maximum; i >= MIN_CHARS; --i)
                                    ^
letter_size_chart.c:38:27: error: expected expression
        for (j = MIN_CHARS; i <= MAX_CHARS; ++i)
                          ^
letter_size_chart.c:48:23: error: expected expression
    for (i = MIN_CHARS; i <= MAX_CHARS; i++) 
                      ^
letter_size_chart.c:50:23: error: expected expression
    for (i = MIN_CHARS; i <= MAX_CHARS; i++) 
                      ^
4 errors generated.
```

What in my loops is causing these errors? Here is my code:

```
/* 
    sorts input by size of words into a histogram
*/

#define EOF -1
#define MAX_CHARS 10    /* max number of chars allowed in a word */
#define MIN_CHARS

#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int c, i, j, word_length, numbcountsize, maximum;
    int numbcount[MAX_CHARS];
    word_length = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (isalpha(c))
            ++word_length;
        else 
            if (word_length != 0)
            {
                ++numbcount[word_length - 1];
                word_length = 0;
            }
    }

    maximum = numbcount[0];
    for (i = MIN_CHARS; i <= MAX_CHARS; i++)
        if (numbcount[i - 1] > maximum)
            maximum = numbcount[i];

    for (i = maximum; i >= MIN_CHARS; --i)
    {
        printf("%d |", i);
        for (j = MIN_CHARS; i <= MAX_CHARS; ++i)
        {
            if (j >= i)
                printf(" * ");
            else 
                printf("   ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("  | ");
    for (i = MIN_CHARS; i <= MAX_CHARS; i++) 
        printf("_");
    for (i = MIN_CHARS; i <= MAX_CHARS; i++) 
        printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Comment: You've not defined `MIN_CHARS` as anything — you need a number after `#define MIN_CHARS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a `#define` with an empty string, i.e.

```
#define MIN_CHARS
```

it tells the preprocessor to *remove* all mentions of `MIN_CHARS` from the text of your program. Effectively, your loop looks like this:

```
for (i =; i <= 10; i++)
```

This is invalid, so C compiler rejects it.

Providing a value for `MIN_CHARS` will fix this problem:

```
#define MIN_CHARS 2
```